# Automatically determine if type is Abstract Base Class via templates at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to automatically determine if a class is an abstract base class at compile time?

I have an object factory that, via other generic code, sometimes gets instantiated with an Abstract Base Class type.  The code doesn't compile because it calls new T() on the ABC.  I end up having to specialize the object factory create code for each ABC to instead assert(0) in this case.  If it were possible to automatically determine if a type is an ABC at compile-time this specialization could be automated.

A simplified example follows:

```
// this program code compiles w/ gcc 4.4
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

// How to automatically specialize this class at compile-time?
template<typename T>
struct isAbstractBaseClass
{
  enum { VALUE = 0 };
};

// Factory to create T, lives in a struct to allow default template parameters
template<typename T, int ABSTRACT = isAbstractBaseClass<T>::VALUE >
struct Create
{
  static T* create()
  {
    return new T();
  }
};

// specialize Create for abstract base classes
template<typename T>
struct Create<T, 1>
{
  static T* create()
  {
    std::cout << "Cannot create and Abstract Base Class!\n";
    std::cout << "Create failed on type_info::name() = " << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
    return 0;
  }
};

struct Foo
{
  Foo() { std::cout << "Foo created\n"; }
};

struct Baz
{
  virtual void bar() = 0; // make this an Abstract Base Class
};

// template specialize on Baz to mark it as an Abstract Base Class
// My Question: is it possible to automatically determine this at compile-time?
template<> class isAbstractBaseClass<Baz> { enum { VALUE = 1 }; };


int main()
{
  std::cout << "Attempting to create a Foo class.\n";
  delete Create<Foo>::create();

  std::cout << "Attempting to create a Baz class.\n";
  delete Create<Baz>::create();

  return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
> c++ abstract.cpp && ./a.out
Attempting to create a Foo class.
Foo created
Attempting to create a Baz class.
Cannot create and Abstract Base Class!
Create failed on type_info::name() = 3Baz
```

**edit 1** @jwismar pointed me towards Boost's is_abstract implementation.  Honestly, looking at the code and trying to deduce what boost is doing is very painful.  Can someone boil down what trick they're using?  (*edit 2* actually, I was looking at the wrong bit of code, and I figured it down below in edit 2)

@raj Yes, there is a constraint that the class must have a default public constructor.  Its not entirely generic, but it provides functionality for 99% of the types I care about.  Adding a create() method is not an option because I don't control some of the classes being wrapped (3rd party code).

@DennisZickefoose The code does compile -- with template specializations to handle ABCs.  Yes, the design could be improved to ensure the code that instantiates the create() method with an ABC doesn't do so, but that code is also performing other duties which make sense on ABCs and non-ABCs alike.  At this point it would be a major re-write and I'm looking for a more short term solution.

Both @raj and @DennisZickefoose make good points about the design of the example and the underlying code base, but I'm really only interested in the topic's question of how to determine ABC-ness of a type at compile time.  Preferably without Boost.  My rationale for such a need is orthogonal to the question at hand.

**edit 2** Since I can't answer my own question with out 100 reputation, I'll post my answer here:

I was able to understand the Boost is_abstract code enough to create a version of isAbstractBaseClass that works for my needs.  It uses [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to fallback to the check_sig(...) version in the case of an ABC type.

```
template<class T>
struct isAbstractBaseClass
{
  // Inspired by boost/type_traits/is_abstract.hpp
  // Deduction fails if T is void, function type, 
  // reference type (14.8.2/2)or an abstract class type 
  // according to review status issue #337
  template<class U>
  static char check_sig(U (*)[1]);
  template<class U>
  static short check_sig(...);
  //
  enum { VALUE = sizeof(isAbstractBaseClass<T>::template check_sig<T>(0)) - 1 };
};
```

Comment: You already have a constraint on your class that it must have a constructor that doesn't take any arguments.  So it is not very generic to begin with. If you force that constraint you might as well have the class have a method called Foo* create() and delegate the responsibility to individual classes and not your object factory

Comment: You should also be weary of classes without accessible default constructors for other reasons.

Comment: I'm also not sure why this isn't already a compile time error without your help. And the generic code that requests a concrete instance of an abstract type is really the one to blame here.

Comment: Oh wait, you want it to compile. That's just silly, your code has a bug that you need to fix if this fails.

Comment: You _can_ answer your own question, but there may be a time limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Boost Type Traits library has an [is_abstract](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_abstract.html) functor. You could either use that directly, or take a look at the implementation and see how they handled it.

Comment: Heh, figures.  Boost seems to be the go-to answer for these sorts of questions.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @McKay Indeed. Those guys rock.

Answer (score 2):

or just remove this:

```
// specialize Create for abstract base classes
template<typename T>
struct Create<T, 1>
{
  static T* create()
  {
    std::cout << "Cannot create and Abstract Base Class!\n";
    std::cout << "Create failed on type_info::name() = " << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
    return 0;
  }
};
```

then the compiler will just emit an error when you try to create an abc.

Comment: Justin, you're entirely missing my point.  It needs to compile and execute.  In the actual code base, there is generic template code that is instantiating create function for all types, including ABCs.  It needs to be compile-able even if the code is never called (the specializations assert(0) if a creator of an ABC is called).

Comment: @McKay: Except that it is impossible to create an abstract type. That's part of their definition. If a program asks that function to be created, you have a bug and it should not compile. Moving the check to run time is ridiculous. Let the type system work for you, that's what it's there for.

Comment: i agree with Dennis here. i find it strange to redirect the flow of instantiation to favor a runtime `assert`ion where a compile error is ideal (imo). i understood *what* you were asking for, not *why*. the OP doesn't provide a reason to avoid the favorable error mechanism - that's why i posted my answer.